# Accepting cookies when web scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Related to a [previous question](https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/Power-system-data/Consumption1/Consumption-prognosis/SE/Hourly/?view=table) I am trying to edit the answer to apply to another website, but can't get it to work. What I want to do here is to accept the cookie, and then extract the information from the table. (I also want to scrape the table for all of 2021 later, so any tips on how to proceed there is welcomed too).

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)#optional
webdriver_service = Service("./chromedriver") #Your chromedriver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service,options=options)

data = []
driver.get('https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/en/Market-data1/Power-system-data/Consumption1/Consumption-prognosis/SE/Hourly/?view=table')
time.sleep(3)

cookie = tbutton = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="pure-button"]'))).click()
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tbutton)
time.sleep(1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")

df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
print(df)
```

> JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click')
> (Session info: chrome=107.0.5304.107)

I inspected the "I accept cookies" button and it seems that `"pure-button"` should be inserted in the class field. What could be the issue here?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `click()` method returns `null`, so this expression `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="pure-button"]'))).click()` returns `null`, so `cookie` and `tbutton` are `null` objects.
Then you trying to click a `null` object with `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tbutton)` and this line gives you an error.
So, in your code you should remove `cookie = tbutton =` and `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", tbutton)` while this line

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="pure-button"]'))).click()
```

is enough. It should close the cookies.
That's it.
Also, this line can be improved.
Since you are clicking that button it's better to use `element_to_be_clickable` expected condition than `visibility_of_element_located`. So, I'd advice this line to be:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="pure-button"]'))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you. That works! It seems though that this is giving me the values from the calendar, and not from the Consumption Values below?

Comment: OK, that's another issue. I handled only the error you presented in the question. For additional issues please ask separate question since each question here in SO should be narrowed to a specific issue.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I figured it out.  I realized that by changing `df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]` to  `df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[1]`  I can extract the second HTML element.